# Sharepoint or Webapp for simple intranet applications?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-applications, access-rights

Need an advice on design approach. I spent couple of hours googling and still cannot come to a conclusion. Task at hand:

- design intranet app that will have access control. Users should be given rights to access it.
- C# is a preferred design language
- app can be a simple form with some text fields and some fields as dropdown boxes from a DB
- app will send SOAP request upon form completion
- there should be a couple more forms like db search, preferably with sorting ability for columns

There is a Sharepoint I can get access to. Can it easily solve the access rights management or or should create a separate app on the same IIS or perhaps I shold request a separate IIS created and deal with access rights via DOTNET solutions? What is the quickest way to design this in your view?

Our SharePoint is 2010, and professional edition of VS2013 available for development.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About SharePoint:

- There is a permission management in SharePoint. You can set user permissions up to individual items, files and pages. You can read about it here: [User permissions and permission levels in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and here: [Fine-grained permission reference for SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169567%28v=office.15%29.aspx). You can use differend authentication providers (AD, FBA, Oauth etc): [Authentication, authorization, and security in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms457529%28v=office.15%29.aspx).
- You can create customization declaratively (no code), С# or javascript. There is built in object model (client and server) and web services (REST for 2013 or SOAP for 2010). [More about SharePoint for developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/dn448478)
- You can use built in form web parts or create custom with server code (C#) or with just HTML and javascript. All you can do with asp.net - you can do in SharePoint with custom web parts. But you can do most of things just with HTML and javascript.
- You can request web services from server code (C#) or from javascript - just like in asp.net apps.
- You can do db search with javascript or server code, using your prefer datagrid controls.

I think most easy way is using SharePoint 2013 Foundation (it's free if you have Windows Server license). And using javascript and HTML - in this way you don't need to know anything about deploying solutions in SharePoint etc. But you can do it via custom web parts - in this way you may do it like common asp.net development. But it's not a best way.

Comment: Looks like SharePoint is the way to go, but as it turns out there are many options within this approach. Could you please add links to your answer supporting all the different options you are recommending? It will help me to make decision.

Comment: @fortran, I'm added some links. SharePoint is a huge topic and I can't cover all, but SharePoint for developers portal is a good startpoint. And you can read some books - it's very usefull to understand SharePoint.